# Why is my server 302-redirecting Lighthouse away from my robots.txt file, but not when I visit it with a web browser?

Tags: seo, html, robots.txt, 302-redirect, lighthouse

This is my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /user/
Disallow: /user/*
Disallow: /home/*
Disallow: /adminpanel/*
Disallow: /Valorant_Guess/*
Disallow: /Leagueoflegends_Guess/*
Disallow: /Rocketlegue_Guess/*
Disallow: /Csgo_Guess/*
Disallow: /Apexlegends_Guess/*
Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

My robots.txt file is visible at `/robots.txt`.

With a commenter's help: It looks like the problem is that my `/robots.txt` path is 302-redirecting to my home page when Lighthouse requests it (`/`), so Lighthouse never even sees my robots.txt. And that this issue is unrelated to the contents of my robots.txt file.

In addition to this, my webapp serves the robots.txt normally when visited by a web browser.

I coded my app on Flask using the gentelella package and the HTML/CSS/JavaScript is a Wella (paid template).

Here is the code of my robots.txt page in Flask:
Edited (corrected the text/plain)

```
@blueprint.route("/robots.txt")
def robots():
  return send_from_directory(current_app.static_folder, 'robots/robots.txt', mimetype='text/plain')
```

And here is the Flask code for my home page:

```
@blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def accueil():
    user_name = session.get("user")
    if (user_name):
        #... unrelated code ...
    return render_template('accueil/index.html' )
```

No redirects have been added in the Flask code.

Edit :
It is not a server related error as Lighthouse has the same errors as when launch the webapp on a server or locally

here is a picture of the error :
[image]

So how can I prevent my app from issuing an erroneous 302-redirect when Lighthouse requests my robots.txt file? It does not issue the same 302 redirect when visited normally in a web browser.

Comment: Your `/robots.txt` path is 302-redirecting to your home page when Lighthouse requests it (`/`), so Lighthouse never even sees your `robots.txt` ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/hI3Odmh.png)). This issue is unrelated to the contents of your `robots.txt` file. You'll need to look into your website's redirect configuration, and remove whatever redirect rule is causing the issue.

Comment: Specifically, you'll need to prevent your web server from 302-redirecting `/robots.txt` to `/` when Lighthouse requests it. For some reason, your website 302-redirects away from your `robots.txt` when Lighthouse requests it, but serves the `robots.txt` normally when visited by a web browser.

Comment: Also, your robots.txt file is being served with a `text/html` content type header, when it should be served with a `text/plain` content type header. This also points to an issue with the server configuration.

Comment: ok thank you. This is really helpfull for me !

Comment: Could nginx be the culprit? 
I set it up with 
'''
server {
    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl;
....
'''

Comment: It's possible that your nginx config could be part of the issue, yes. Now that we know the biggest issue is the 302-redirect, look carefully through your server configuration and website code to see if there might be something causing it. If you're stumped, I would ask a new question (or edit to completely replace this question), including your nginx configuration, more details about how your site is coded (static html? php? single page app?), and a problem statement like "Why is my server 302-redirecting Lighthouse away from my robots.txt file, but not when I visit it with a web browser?"

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit of redirects crawlers!
In my flask app I used `flask_paranoid`.
The package protects the application against certain attacks in which the user session cookie is stolen and then used by the attacker.

the command

```
paranoid.redirect_view = '/'
```

was redirecting all the crawlers.

For the moment I have no idea how to make them compatible with one another.